# Can Bhaskara's Wheel increase the efficiency of wind mills?

Tags: perpetual-motion, renewable-energy

[Bhaskara's wheel](https://lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/museum/overbal.htm) is an ancient attempt at perpetual motion. The idea is that gravity will pull the water toward the center for the bottles at the top  and toward the ends for the bottles falling to the bottom. Perpetual motion aside, would such a set up increase the efficiency of a wind mill? Specifically, half filling the wind mill blades with fluid.

https://lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/museum/overbal.htm

[image: Bhaskara's wheel]

Comment: Since it doesn't work for perpetual motion, why do you think it would increase the efficiency? Not even counting why you would want a lot of weight sloshing around inside a giant blade and messing up the bearings...

Comment: The sloshing is going to dissipate energy as heat, so it is pretty sure to lower performance.

Comment: Discussion of perpetual motion machnes similar to this: https://lockhaven.edu/~dsimanek/museum/overbal.htm

Answer (score 1):

Bhaskara's wheel, and all the variations of it which have been invented over the years, do not work as he and those other inventors thought they should. Adding it to any other machine cannot possibly improve that machine's performance, and in fact can only detract from it, as pointed out by Jon and Anders.